# How to check if a model with certain values exist in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I'm doing a project with an API and in the API there's an object, let's call it `userGrades`. It looks like this:

```js
"userGrades" : [ 
  {"buytime": value, grade: "Audi", "expiretime": "value"}, 
  {"buytime": value, grade: "BW", "expiretime": "value"}
]
```

This API is connected to a fivem server and if the player buys a car license for BW, let's say the licence gets added to this array now, I need to check if he has a BW license and respond with a yes or no. If I manage to find that out I can manage from there, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check if at least one element exists in an array where the `grade` is `"BW"`. Check out the snippet below:

```js
const obj = {
  userGrades: [
    {
      buytime: 'value',
      grade: 'Audi',
      expiretime: 'value',
    },
    {
      buytime: 'value',
      grade: 'BW',
      expiretime: 'value',
    },
  ],
};

const hasBW = obj.userGrades.some((i) => i.grade === 'BW');
const hasAudi = obj.userGrades.some((i) => i.grade === 'Audi');
const hasXX = obj.userGrades.some((i) => i.grade === 'XX');

console.log({ hasAudi, hasBW, hasXX });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether it has a null value or not.

In your case you can store the value in a `variable` and then access that object. Let's say you stored that object in variable called `xyz`.

```
console.log(xyz[1]['grade'])  //xyz here is that array of objects
```

If the above prints undefined then there was no value in it hence user does not have a BW licence and vide versa. You could use this in an `if` statement probably.

Comment: Indeed that would work if I have precisely 2 models in the object and the second one its the one I need but you see this api is dynamic I mean like sometime the object has 2 models like in the example but sometime it has 3 models or only one and I have no way of knowing where the one for wich I need to check is in the array

Comment: You can always loop through that array and check for each one and if you find then you can also store the index value in a variable. Will that solve you doubt ???